# "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" on line 25

Tags: c++

I've been working on a C++ Autoclicker project for fun, and I noticed an error saying "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" on line 25. Could someone help me figure this one out?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int x;
int y;

int cps(int clicks)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter desired cps (clicks per second)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> clicks;

    return clicks;
}

bool clicking()
{

    // clicker{ cps };
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MBUTTON))
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(rand() % cps / 1000);
    }

} 



int main()
{
    std::thread(cps).join();
    std::thread(clicking).join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please figure out which is line 25 ;)

Comment: `Sleep(rand() % cps / 1000);`   `cps` is a function did you mean to call it?

Comment: `cps` is a function, so `rand() % cps` does not make sense. Also, the `cps` function wants an argument, and why it wants that is a mystery since it never uses its value.

Comment: I want it to click at a random interval

Comment: line 25 is sleep rand

Comment: Why are you starting threads, only to join them immediately? Your `main` is the same as `cps(); clicking();`, but with additional overhead.

Comment: i fixed the thread thing, now it just directly calls.

Comment: As an alternative to identifying line 25, you could create a [mre], which likely would have only one statement plus declarations, maybe some skeleton function definitions. Likely the error would be from that one statement.

Comment: You probably want to take the result of `cps` and give it to `clicking`: `int main() { int clicks = cps(); clicking(clicks);}` The `cps` function doesn't need a parameter, it can use a local variable.

Comment: How can you call cps without an argument? `Sleep(rand() % cps / 1000);`

Comment: Also going forward it could be beneficial to include all line numbers or highlight line 25 for us like the debugger is doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

> “expression must have integral or unscoped enum type” on line 25

```
Sleep(rand() % cps / 1000);
```

^ cps is a function and it takes input and it takes an argument, you're not calling it like a function, you would need to do cps(5) or something like that.  But the code is not good and can be greatly simplified and enhanced with the desired outcome like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(200, 1000);

    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON))
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sleep(20);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            int random_value = distribution(generator);
            Sleep(random_value);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While holding the right mouse button this will perform a left click randomly at intervals between 200 and 1000 milliseconds.  The additional Sleep(20) will give extra time to ensure your target window detects the left click.